# How to get last n records from n different tables in SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to get the last record of all the available tables from my database, e.g:

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1 (
    "name"  TEXT,
    "price" NUMERIC,
    "amount"    INTEGER,
    "value" INTEGER
)
```

and

```
Table2 (
    "name"  TEXT,
    "price" NUMERIC,
    "amount"    INTEGER,
    "value" INTEGER
)
```

When i add something on the Tables the value record variable goes value = value + 1 and so on, something like id. I want to get the last record in every Table with the max(value) and print that record name,price and amount from all the different Tables available.

I have made it with this code in python :

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE value=(SELECT max(value) FROM Table1)")
data = cur.fetchall()
for row in data:
   print("", row[0], "\t Χ ", row[2], "\t %0.2f" % row[1],"€")
```

but i can do this only by repeating this code twice (or n-times for Table1,Table2...TableN). I want an easy way to make this work without repeating the code above for N-times (TableN) in my program.

Also i have try to do:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.value=(SELECT max(Table1.value) FROM Table1) AND Table2.value=(SELECT max(Table2.value) FROM Table2)")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. If you have multiple tables all with the same columns it's probably a bad DB design. Anyway, what you want can be done, but what do you expect the resulting record to look like if all your columns in all your tables have the same name?

Comment: e.g Table1("salad", "3.00", "1", "0") and Table2("beef","7.00","3","1") this is the last records in 2 Tables for an order, i want to be able to print that last selected records that is the order that a customer make. The N-different tables is to be able to have N-different categories to storage the items from the orders.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, bad design. Just add a "category" column and use only one table. And if you want to stick to your N-tables design and do not want to copy&paste the same code N-time just wrap it in a loop and build the sql statement dynamically. Again, if you want a single-query solution (that returns only one record for ally our N-tables), you will have a hard time to figure out what row index belongs to what table.